# What is the most efficient way to filter a large list of Javascript objects into a 2D array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a large array of objects (>1,000) in my javascript program, and I also have a smaller array of other arrays containing keys related to each other (each key has a corresponding object in the larger array). I would like to search through the large array in the most efficient way possible, creating a 2-dimensional array of objects matching the keys of the smaller array. What is the best way to go about doing this? I have tried using the filter method on the larger array but I believe that that could only result in a 1-dimensional array, and not the desired nesting of related objects.

Here is an illustration of the problem:

Large array of objects:

```
[{ key: 'misc1' },
{ key: 'misc2' },
{ key: 'firstRelatedValue1' },
{ key: 'firstRelatedValue2' },
{ key: 'secondRelatedValue1' },
{ key: 'secondRelatedValue2' },
...]
```

Smaller 2D array of keys:

```
[
['firstRelatedValue1', 'firstRelatedValue2'],
['secondRelatedValue1', 'secondRelatedValue2']
]
```

Intended end result:

```
[
[{ key: 'firstRelatedValue1' }, { key: 'firstRelatedValue2' }],
[{ key: 'secondRelatedValue1' }, { key: 'secondRelatedValue2' }]
]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve this on your own? The simplest approach would be a set of `for` loops

Comment: Will there always be two _"keys"_ in every array in the _"smaller"_ array? Do all keys (from the sub-array) have to match?

Comment: @Andreas The only way I have found to limit the number of loops over the large array to 1 is to keep the array of keys as a 1-dimensional list and using that to filter the large array, but this is not the intended result. If I were to use a set of for loops over the array of keys, it would require multiple passes over the larger array (which is inefficient). If possible I would like to minimize the loops over the larger array.

Comment: @Andreas In the actual program there are three keys per smaller array but yes.

Comment: It is really unclear how the smaller one applies to the larger one.

Comment: @epascarello The smaller one contains keys for a selection of objects from the larger one. The reason I want to keep the keys in a 2D array is because some of the keys are closely related, being multiple aspects of the same thing. I cannot change the structure of the larger array.